# What is the meaning of "SGD scales the gradient uniformly in all directions"?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent, gradient, stochastic-gradient-descent

I'm really newbie about neural network and optimization. When I read the references, I found this journal [Wang et al 2018](https://www.matec-conferences.org/articles/matecconf/pdf/2018/91/matecconf_eitce2018_03007.pdf).

The journal stated:

> One disadvantage of SGD
> is that it scales the gradient uniformly in all directions;
> this can be particularly detrimental for ill-scaled
> problems. This also makes the process of tuning the
> learning rate α circumstantially laborious

What does it mean by "it scales the gradient uniformly in all directions"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What it's getting at, is the step size you use should depend on the *curvature* , ie how the gradient changes in *each* direction.

Imagine a narrow u-shaped sloping valley.in the direction of the U, you want to take a very small step size or you will shoot up the other side ( the gradient has actually changed direction). Along the valley, in the perpendicular direction - with low curvature - you want a large step size.

the step size you need should be large in directions that curvature is small and gradient stays roughly the same, and small in directions that the gradient is changing rapidly.

with gradient descent, you have a fixed stepsize in all directions. So in the situation of "ill-scaled" problems, where the curvature is not the same in all directions (eg  u-shape valley example). You need to choose a very small step size so you don't constantly overshoot, which means that you will travel very slowly along the valley floor.

Comment: (+1) well explanations

Answer (score 6):

The gradient vector is multiplied by a scalar constant called learning rate, i.e.
$$\theta_{t+1}=\theta_t-\alpha\nabla_\theta L$$
where $\theta$ is the parameter, $L$ is the loss. This means every dimension of the gradient vector is multiplied by the same constant, i.e. scaled uniformly in all directions.

Comment: In the context of the gradient itself, what do all directions mean? is the positive direction negative? or how? sorry I'm not too familiar with gradients

Comment: Gradient is just a vector. All directions means each element of the vector, like x, y, z directions. It's not about positivity or negativity.

Comment: but isn't gradient the Slope of a Straight Line?

Comment: Slope in *all* directions, which is a vector.